# Apply Regex into a textbox form VBA

Tags: regex, excel, vba, textbox

I need your help guys. How can I limit my textboxes? This is my Form Below.
[image]

What I need is to create if statement for the following textboxes:
Pallet ID: Must only contain 9 numbers
Carton ID: Must only contain 10 numbers
Serials (all 6): Must startwith FOC and only contain CAPS and Numbers [A-Z][0-9]

I did this in Javascript but now I need to have a backup in a excelsheet. Any ideas?

Thanks for your attention,

Comment: Set the `MaxLength` property for each box, and handle textbox events, e.g. `txtPalletID_KeyDown` if you want to intercept individual keys (and actually *prevent* them from even being entered in the first place), or `txtPalletID_Exit` to validate the content when the focus switches to another control (and possibly cancel it and force the focus back into the textbox); that way you can make the `Agregar` button disabled until all fields are known to be valid... but that's quite broad a subject for a single SO question. Try something, get stuck, come back with a *specific* issue =)

Comment: let me give it a try thanks :)

Comment: @Deluq read my answer and code below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'v created a sample `User_Form` and a `CommandButton` (like a "confirm" button) that's once it's pressed it checks that all the values entered in the `TextBox`es are according to the rules.

The code below will get you started, it checks the values in "Pallet ID" (9-digits) and "Carton ID" (10-digits).

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Reg1 As Object
Dim Reg2 As Object

Dim RegMatches As Object

' ====== Test PalletID_Tb =====
Set Reg1 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With Reg1
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "\d{9,9}" ' Match any set of 9 digits
End With

Set RegMatches = Reg1.Execute(Me.PalletID_Tb.Value)

If RegMatches.Count = 1 Then '<-- make sure there is only 1 match (9 digits and not 18 or 27)
    MsgBox "Value in Pallet ID is OK"
Else
    MsgBox "Pallet ID must have a 9 digit format"
    Me.PalletID_Tb.Value = ""
    Exit Sub
End If

' ====== Test CartonID_Tb =====
Set Reg2 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With Reg2
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "\d{10,10}" ' Match any set of 10 digits
End With

Set RegMatches = Reg2.Execute(Me.CartonID_Tb.Value)

If RegMatches.Count = 1 Then '<-- make sure there is only 1 match (10 digits and not 20)
    MsgBox "Value in Carton ID is OK"
Else
    MsgBox "Carton ID must have a 10 digit format"
    Me.CartonID_Tb.Value = ""
    Exit Sub
End If

' Do something if passed the 2 conditions

End Sub
```

Comment: Shai, Thanks for your time !