# How do i edit this VBA code to accept different values?

Tags: excel, vba

Having some trouble getting this online copypasta working correctly. First character must be A to Z, second character 1 to 5, third character "" or 0 to 9.

Box function is to specify a cell in Range A1:Z53.

Ideas on syntax?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
Select Case KeyAscii
    Case Asc("0") To Asc("9")
    Case Asc("-")
        If Instr(1,Me.TextBox1.Text,"-") > 0 Or Me.TextBox1.SelStart > 0 Then
            KeyAscii = 0
        End If
    Case Asc(".")
        If InStr(1, Me.TextBox1.Text, ".") > 0 Then
            KeyAscii = 0
        End If
    Case Else
        KeyAscii = 0
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Excel dialogs can be used to select range https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643541/how-to-generate-the-range-selection-dialog-box-using-vba-in-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, but I got a good tip to use RegEx. This ended up being the best solution for my application. After searching i found a previous answer that just needed the following modification to work in this scenario:

```
.IgnoreCase = False

.Pattern = "[A-Z]([1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|[5][0-3])$"
```

Code can be found here:
[Apply Regex into a textbox form VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41857339/apply-regex-into-a-textbox-form-vba)

Answer (score 1):

VBA has limited pattern matching using the [`Like` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator) :

```
IsInRange = text Like "[A-Z][1-9]" Or text Like "[A-Z][1-4][0-9]" Or text Like "[A-Z]5[0-3]"
```

---

Another alternative can be using the Excel intersect method (will also work with for example "`$Z$53`") :

```
IsInRange = Not Intersect([A1:Z53], Range(text)) Is Nothing
```

or Excel [range intersect operator](http://www.theexcelbible.com/excel-tips/intersect-operator-in-excel/) :

```
IsInRange = Not Evaluate("ISERR(A1:Z53 " & text & ")")
```